# Which Shanghai airport is closest to the Langham Xintiandi Hotel?

Tags: airports, shanghai, pvg, sha

Which Shanghai airport is closest to the Langham Xintiandi Hotel? Hongqiao or Pudong airports?

Comment: I downvoted because this question does not show a lot of research effort.

Answer (score 4):

Hongqiao is MUCH closer. As google maps shows, the road from the hotel to [Hongqiao](http://goo.gl/maps/orHoi) is only 15 km, while it's over 40 [to Pudong](http://goo.gl/maps/hR2cn).